# How to get acceptance rate from pymc pickle database

Tags: python, pymc, mcmc

I'm using the method below to get the acceptance rate after a MCMC run with pymc (inspired by [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120028/2-gaussian-mixture-model-inference-with-mcmc-and-pymc/120348#120348)):

```
MDL.step_method_dict[next(iter(MDL.stochastics))][0].ratio
```

(or is there a simpler way?)

But if I save the MDL into a pickle database, then load it again (following the procedure described [here](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/database.html)) and running the same command as above, I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'Database' object has no attribute 'step_method_dict'
```

Answer (score 0):

The acceptance ratio is not recoverable, and was never intended to be accessed by users. Note also that the acceptance ratio is continually being reset through the sampling procedure every time there is an adaptive tuning step, so the ratio is only for the interval from the last tuning.

Comment: I see, thanks. I have used the acceptance rate as a good indicator for pursuing the chain or not, especially if the parameters are strongly correlated (or do you have a better advice?). In general being able to check  a number of diagnostics is very useful.

Comment: You can get similar information from just looking at the trace. If you plot a trace with a very low acceptance rate, it has particular characteristics; similarly a trace with a very high acceptance rate. So you don't really need the number to evaluate. I would use a formal diagnostic (e.g. Gelman-Rubin) rather than this, however.